# How to make string evaluation to change component's variable in Angular/Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, evaluation

I have a component with the local variables in it like this:

```
trainingColumns = 1;
trainingAttempts = 2;
```

and so on

Then, it the http response handler I'd like to execute the string with business rule, coming from the rest backend. I'd like to make it as agile as possible and not hardcode, so I don't like to parse this String for values, but instead I'd like it to be evaluated and change the values of the component's local variable, like this:

```
   this.trainingColumns = 2;
```

I tried just to put the above String to

```
(window as any).eval("this.trainingColumns = 2;");
```

and have not succeed, the component's variables has not changed. So, what is the correct Angular/Typescript way for doing that? Not that at some point I may require,say,

```
   (window as any).eval("this.trainingColumns = 2; this.trainingAttempts = 1;");
```

or even something more complex.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? What is that supposed to means: I'd like to execute the string with business rule?

Comment: @ukn do code some component variables changes not in component, but in strings obtained to it dynamically with ajax requests

Comment: What exactly is your backend returning?

Comment: Just "evaling" random JavaScript sent to you over the net. What could possibly go wrong...

Comment: Guys, @BenjaminMaurer when that is requested please consider all security risks are not neglected, but are not possible because of other ways protecting from the malicious code (and the most one being no third party valuble data on the client side). It is clearly seen that any possible js code being evaluated when it is inserted through the database strings can be an injection but here not a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using eval could be dangerous this should get you started...

```
name: string = "";

ngOnInit() {
  var obj = this as object;
  eval("obj.name = 'hello world'")
  console.log(this.name) // hello world
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! really, no places all over the internet to get the understanding how it can be done if REALLY needed